# entityManager.GetTransaction().Commit() returns void, how to get autogenerated ID of entity?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, persistence

I am using NHibernate & Net Persistence API with C# in my project. I have the following Save method:

```
        public void Save(IGenericEntity entity)
        {
            _entityManager = GetEm();
            _entityManager.GetTransaction().Begin();
            _entityManager.Persist(entity);
            _entityManager.Flush();            
            _entityManager.GetTransaction().Commit();            
            _entityManager.Clear();
        }
```

Now say entity has a field ID (which is auto-generated value from db). Now I am saving this entity, and I want either auto-generated ID or saved entity in return, but.Commit() return type is void. Anyone can please guide about this?

I have used hibernate with Java, and there by calling .save() it returns the saved entity  (with auto-generated ID). How to achieve the same in above context?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the call to #flush your entity will have the id in it. Try this test:

```
Save( entity );
assertNotNull( entity.getId() );
```

Comment: It gave id in line - _entityManager.Persist(entity);
Thanks!